# enviar datos de un fragment a una activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

tengo un problema... cuando hago click en el item( que está dentro de un fragment) me direciona a una activity pero solo me sale el dato del "title"... la "image" y "lugar" me sale vacio

```
 public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
            .setQuery(mRef, Model.class)
            .build();
      FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ofertasViewHolder> adapter =new 
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ofertasViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ofertasViewHolder holder, 
    int position, @NonNull Model model) {

            final String mImage = getItem(position).getImage();
            final String mTitle = getItem(position).getTitle();
            final String mLugar = getItem(position).getLugar();

            Picasso.get().load(mImage).into(holder.oImagenvw);
            holder.oTitletv.setText(mTitle);
            holder.oLugartv.setText(mLugar);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ejemplo_item_ofertas.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
                    intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                    intent.putExtra("image", mLugar);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ofertasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ejemplo_item2, viewGroup,false);
            return new ofertasViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
public static class ofertasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView oTitletv,oLugartv;
    ImageView oImagenvw;

    public ofertasViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        oImagenvw=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView2);
        oTitletv= itemView.findViewById(R.id.rTitle2Tv);
        oLugartv= itemView.findViewById(R.id.rLugar2Tv);
```

aca es donde se recibe los datos que es la activity

```
    TextView bTitletv,bLugartv;
    ImageView bImagevw;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ejemplo_item_ofertas);

    bImagevw=findViewById(R.id.dImagevw);
    bTitletv=findViewById(R.id.dTitletv);
    bLugartv=findViewById(R.id.dLugartv);

    String image=getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String lugar=getIntent().getStringExtra("lugar");

    Picasso.get().load(image).into(bImagevw);
    bTitletv.setText(title);
    bLugartv.setText(lugar);
```

Comment: Revisa que valor tienen las variables mImage  y mLugar  antes de realizar el Intent

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es enviar un array con la información que ocupas recibir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas enviando y recibiendo correctamente los valores.

Hay dos posibles razones de problema:

La razón por la que no recibas los valores, es que las variables no tengan valor al realizar el `intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ejemplo_item_ofertas.class);
intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
intent.putExtra("image", mLugar);
startActivity(intent);
```

O que en realidad esta no sea la Activity `ejemplo_item_ofertas` :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ejemplo_item_ofertas);

    ...
    ...

    String image=getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String lugar=getIntent().getStringExtra("lugar");
    ...
    ...
  }
```